# Differentiation of Matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I’ll appreciate any help on this.

Given $\mathbf{X}\in {{R}^{m\times n}}$ and $\mathbf{a,b}\in {{R}^{m\times 1}}$, consider $f(\mathbf{{{X}^{T}}a})$ to be an element-wise operation, i.e.,
    \begin{equation} f( \mathbf{{{X}^{T}}a})=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   f( {{v}_{1}})  \\
   \ldots   \\
   f\left( {{v}_{n}} \right)  \\
\end{matrix} \right]=\mathbf{w}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{{{X}^{T}}a=v}$ and $f$ is a sigmoid function defined as $f\left( x \right)=1/\left( 1+{{e}^{-x}} \right)$. What is $\partial \mathbf{w^T w} / \partial \mathbf{X}$?

Comment: Maybe start by applying the product and chain rule on the RHS of $\frac{\partial \mathbf{w^T w}}{ \partial \mathbf{X}} = \frac{\partial f(\mathbf{{{X}^{T}}a})^Tf(\mathbf{{{X}^{T}}a})}{ \partial \mathbf{X}}
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Erik Miehling has helpfully pointed out, you would require the product and chain rule.

We have 
$\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}=\sum_{k=1}^nf(v_k)^2$

Therefore, using the chain rule

$$\frac{d\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}}{dv_g}=2f(v_g)\frac{df(v_g)}{dv_g}$$

We are given that $f(x)=1/(1+e^{-x})$, thus

$$\frac{df(v_g)}{dv_g}=\frac{e^{-v_g}}{(1+e^{-v_g})^2}$$

Thus

$$\frac{d\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}}{dv_g}=2f(v_g)\frac{e^{-v_g}}{(1+e^{-v_g})^2}$$

Now scalar $v_g$ is the product of row $g$ of matrix $\mathbf{X}^T$ and column vector $\mathbf{a}$, i.e.

$$v_g=\sum_{k=1}^mX_{k,g}a_k$$

where $X_{k,g}$ is the element of matrix $\mathbf{X}$ in row $k\in \{1,2,..,m\}$ and column $g\in \{1,2,..,n\}$.

Thus for $f\in \{1,2,..,m\}$

$$\frac{dv_g}{dX_{f,g}}=a_f$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{d\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}}{dX_{f,g}}=\frac{d\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}}{dv_g}\frac{dv_g}{dX_{f,g}}=2f(v_g)\frac{e^{-v_g}}{(1+e^{-v_g})^2}a_f$$

Having dealt with a single element of matrix $\mathbf{X}$, we can extend the derivative to the entire matrix as follows:-

$$\frac{d\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}}{d\mathbf{X}}=\mathbf{AD}$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with $n$ identical columns - each column containing $m$ rows, $[a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_m]$, thus

$$\mathbf{A}=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
a_1 & a_1 & \cdots & a_1  \\
a_2 & a_2 & \cdots & a_2 \\
a_3 & a_3 & \cdots & a_3 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_m & a_m & \cdots & a_m \end{array} \right)$$

and $\mathbf{D}$ is an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix of the form, where the $r$th diagonal element contains $2f(v_r)\frac{e^{-v_r}}{(1+e^{-v_r})^2}$, where $r\in\{1,2,..,n\}$.

$$\mathbf{D}=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
2f(v_1)\frac{e^{-v_1}}{(1+e^{-v_1})^2} & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 2f(v_2)\frac{e^{-v_2}}{(1+e^{-v_2})^2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2f(v_n)\frac{e^{-v_n}}{(1+e^{-v_n})^2} \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks! I have one additional question, suppose I have  \begin{equation} f( \mathbf{{{X}^{T}}b})=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   f( {{u}_{1}})  \\
   \ldots   \\
   f\left( {{u}_{n}} \right)  \\
\end{matrix} \right]=\mathbf{z}
\end{equation} where ${X}^{T}b=u$ and that I want to take $\partial \mathbf{w^T z} / \partial X$ now. Would the answer be $A * D + B* D2$ where $D=diag([f(u_1 )  df(v_1 )/(dv_1 ),…,f(u_n )  df(v_n )/(dv_n )])$, $D=diag([f(v_1 )  df(u_1 )/(du_1 ),…,f(v_n )  df(u_n )/(du_n )])$ and $A, B$ is the vectors $a,b$ replicated columnwise, respectively?

Comment: You are thinking along the right lines, and your answer is correct. We have $$\frac{\partial \mathbf{w^Tz}}{\partial X_{f,g}}=f(v_g)\frac{\partial f(u_g)}{\partial u_g}\frac{\partial u_g}{\partial X_{f,g}}+f(u_g)\frac{\partial f(v_g)}{\partial v_g}\frac{\partial v_g}{\partial X_{f,g}}$$ So the answer is $A*D+B*D2$, where $D=diag[f(u_1)df(v_1)/(dv_1),...,f(u_n)df(v_n)/(dv_n)]$ and $D2=diag[f(v_1)df(u_1)/(du_1),...,f(v_n)df(u_n)/(du_n)]$

Answer (score 2):

This sigmoid function is interesting because $f' = f-f^2$, which allows us to simplify the result to
$$
 \frac {\partial w^Tw} {\partial X} = 2 a (w^{\circ 2}-w^{\circ 3})^T
$$
Let's use the notation $w' = f'(v)$, which is analogous to $w = f(v)$.

Let $a\circ b$ denote the Hadamard (element-wise) product of vectors $a, b$.

Hadamard powers are defined as 
$$ \eqalign {
a^{\circ 2} &= a\circ a \cr
a^{\circ 3} &= a\circ a\circ a \cr
etc
}$$
Let $A : B$ denote the Frobenius (scalar) product of matrices $A, B$.

Now it's just a matter of taking differentials
$$\eqalign{
  d(w^Tw) &= 2 w^T dw \cr
       &= 2 w^T (w' \circ dv) \cr
       &= 2 (w\circ w')^T dv \cr
       &= 2 (w\circ w')^T (dX^T a) \cr
       &= 2 a(w\circ w')^T : dX \cr
       &= 2 a(w\circ (w-w^{\circ 2}))^T : dX \cr
} $$
And we see the derivative, as stated above, in the final line.

Comment: Since, in the accepted answer, $A=a1^T$ and also $1^T D = (2f\circ f')^T$, that means $AD = 2a(f\circ f')^T$, which is what @lynne derived in this answer by completely different logics.

Comment: Awesome answer.